# GetFieldID fails on Android 4.4 and older

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'd like to use a dlib library for face detection, but it doesn't work on old phones.

I crashes with the following stack trace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 4288): FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-1-thread-1
E/AndroidRuntime( 4288): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
E/AndroidRuntime( 4288):    at com.tzutalin.dlibtest.MainActivity.runDetectAsync(MainActivity.java:235)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4288):    at com.tzutalin.dlibtest.MainActivity_.access$301(MainActivity_.java:34)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4288):    at com.tzutalin.dlibtest.MainActivity_$6.execute(MainActivity_.java:158)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4288):    at org.androidannotations.api.BackgroundExecutor$Task.run(BackgroundExecutor.java:405)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4288):    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:442)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4288):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4288):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4288):    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:150)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4288):    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:264)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4288):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4288):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4288):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4288): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no field with name='mLabel' signature='java/lang/String' in class Lcom/tzutalin/dlib/VisionDetRet;
E/AndroidRuntime( 4288):    at com.tzutalin.dlib.PeopleDet.jniNativeClassInit(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4288):    at com.tzutalin.dlib.PeopleDet.<clinit>(PeopleDet.java:42)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4288):    ... 12 more
```

So, the C code looks like this:

```cpp
void JNIEXPORT DLIB_JNI_METHOD(jniNativeClassInit)(JNIEnv* env, jclass _this) {
  jclass detRetClass = env->FindClass("com/tzutalin/dlib/VisionDetRet");
  CHECK_NOTNULL(detRetClass);
  gVisionDetRetOffsets.label =
      env->GetFieldID(detRetClass, "mLabel", "java/lang/String");
  gVisionDetRetOffsets.confidence =
      env->GetFieldID(detRetClass, "mConfidence", "F");
  gVisionDetRetOffsets.left = env->GetFieldID(detRetClass, "mLeft", "I");
  gVisionDetRetOffsets.top = env->GetFieldID(detRetClass, "mTop", "I");
  gVisionDetRetOffsets.right = env->GetFieldID(detRetClass, "mRight", "I");
  gVisionDetRetOffsets.bottom = env->GetFieldID(detRetClass, "mBottom", "I");
  gVisionDetRetOffsets.addLandmark =
      env->GetMethodID(detRetClass, "addLandmark", "(II)Z");
  if (gVisionDetRetOffsets.addLandmark == NULL) {
    LOG(FATAL) << "Can't Find Method addLandmark(int,int)";
  }
  LOG(INFO) << "JniNativeClassIni Success";
}
```

And the related Java class:

```java
public final class VisionDetRet {
    private String mLabel;
    private float mConfidence;
    private int mLeft;
    private int mTop;
    private int mRight;
    private int mBottom;
    private ArrayList<Point> mLandmarkPoints = new ArrayList<>();

    VisionDetRet() {
    }

    // Other code
}
```

So, the fields are obviously here, and it gets the class (`CHECK_NOTNULL(detRetClass)` succeeds). So why is it crashing on older phones? Google didn't helped much, and I'm pretty new to NDK/JNI stuff.

P. S. The Java file is [here](https://github.com/tzutalin/dlib-android-app/blob/master/dlib/src/main/java/com/tzutalin/dlib/VisionDetRet.java#L31) and the C file is [here](https://github.com/tzutalin/dlib-android/blob/c58749afa11e0fa01dd9b5d47e46488746484d3a/jni/jnilib_ex/jni_people_det.cpp#L59) (yup, they are in 2 different repos)

Comment: Tip: Use something like this whenever JNI-style signatures are needed: `javap -s -classpath yourBinDirectory com.tzutalin.dlib.VisionDetRef  | grep -A 2 "mLabel"` (If you don't have grep, you must be on Windows. Get using [Gow](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki) If you don't have Gow, get it using [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how this has worked for you on any Android version, because `java/lang/String` is an incorrect signature for `GetFieldID`.

For classes, the signature should be `L fully-qualified-class ;`, so in your case you'd want `Ljava/lang/String;`