# App working on API 25 to 21 but not under API 19

Tags: android, c++, api, java-native-interface

I've coded a app where Java call C++ code after a press on button. 
App work as expected on API 25 to 21 but not under 19, trouble seems to be on C++ code.

```
jclass cls = env->FindClass("<PATH_TO_CLASS_");  
assert(cls != NULL);  
jfieldID info5_ID = env->GetFieldID(cls, "info5", "java/lang/String");  
assert(info5_ID != NULL);
```

On android API 25 to 21 :
info5_ID is different from NULL and app go on

On android API 19 and under :
info5_ID is NULL so assert doest it job...

Is there a workaround or something like that? I've made my some research nothing found except this thread [Android App crashes on API level 19 but works fine on API above 19](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41429936/android-app-crashes-on-api-level-19-but-works-fine-on-api-above-19)
But I a not sure if this should be use for my app.

Here is my manisfest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="cpi.testjniapi19">

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

  <application
      android:name=".Adi"
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:supportsRtl="true"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
      android:vmSafeMode="true">
      <activity
          android:name=".MainActivity"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait">
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
              <category   android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
          </intent-filter>
      </activity>
  </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks in advance,
Clmnt

Comment: What class are you accessing with `FindClass`?

Comment: a custom class : Adi. The path is com/testjniapi19/Adi with some int and string that I use across the two activity of my app. In the java I access those variable with `Adi vars = (Adi) getApplication();`

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39915937/getfieldid-fails-on-android-4-4-and-older  It's saying `"java/lang/String"` is invalid and should be `"Ljava/lang/String"`

Comment: OH many thanks! But I still don't know why it was working with an API greater than 19. Please make an answer and I will accept it :)

Comment: Android 5.0 (API level 21) replaced the Dalvik runtime with ART. So my guess is that Google did something in the class lookup in ART to handle missing semicolons in class signatures. I suppose you could dig through [the ART source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/art/+/master) if you really want to find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Richard Critten was pointing, changing `"java/lang/String"` to `"Ljava/lang/String;"`has resolved the problem.
**_/!\_Don't forget the ";"_/!\_**
Kudos Richard.